MathML in KaTeX Output
I noticed that my KaTeX pipeline inserts MathML elements into the document, which don't seem to get displayed.  This is the CSS:
.katex .katex-mathml {
  clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

I wonder what is the reason for this, and would it improve rendering speed, if I just set them to display: none; globally?

This is a common technique to hide content visually, but still have it accessible by screen readers - https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/ Setting display: none instead would make this content inaccessible in screen readers.

Ah I see, thanks a lot!
